# How to use original hashCode() method after overriding it

Tags: java

//Student.java

```
class Student{
private int roll;
private String name;

    public Student(int roll,String name){
    this.roll=roll;
    this.name=name;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
    return roll+name.length();
    }

    public  boolean equals(Object obj){
    Student s=(Student)obj;
    return (this.roll==s.roll && this.name.equals(s.name));
    }

}
```

//IssueID.java

```
class IssueID{

    public static void issueID(Student s1,Student s2){

    if(s1.equals(s2))
    System.out.println("New ID issued");

    else
    System.out.println("New ID NOT issued");

    }

}
```

//Institute.java

```
import java.lang.Object;
class Institute{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Student s1=new Student(38,"shiva");
    Student s2=new Student(45,"aditya");

    IssueID.issueID(s1,s2);


    System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(s2.hashCode());
    }

}
```

As in the above code, I've overridden the `hashCode()` method. This may sound silly, but can I access `java.lang.Object.hashCode()` method using the same Student objects(s1 and s2) at the same time?

Comment: `super.hashCode()`, but that would be of no use IMHO.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, with [`System.identityHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned by the default method hashCode(), whether or not the given object's class overrides hashCode().

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.identityHashCode` or `super.hashCode()` Also, you should write a better hash code as any students with the sum of the length of the name and roll being equal will have the same hash code. Like (9, "Bob") and (7, "Steve"). That will open up many potential problems for future bugs. Save yourself the headaches and write something like this:

```
 public int hashCode() {
      int hash = 31 * roll;
      hash = 31 * hash + name.hashCode();
      return hash;
 }
```

Also, be aware that your equals method doesn't satisfy the equals method in the JLS.

`this.equals(null)` should return false, yours will throw a ClassCastException.

That could also lead to bugs in the future.

Comment: yeah! that hashcode method is just for test. Anyways thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

write something like this:

```
class Student {
    public int originalHashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

then call s.originalHashCode() when you want to use the original one~